# req.body is always an empty object: {}

Tags: http, express, post, fetch

I can't figure out why my express app never gets the correct `body` data from the client. For express, I have the following:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    next();
});
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/authenticate', async (req, res) => {
    debugger;
    res.send(req.body);
});
```

And for my front end, I just run the following code:

```
await fetch("http://localhost:3000/authenticate", {
    method: "POST",
    body: "anything"
})
```

But in the request handler, `req.body` is always `{}`. I tried sending strings, JSON objects, stringified JSON objects, but no matter what, it always comes out to `{}`.

The only thing I could think of is that the front-end is on a different domain (it's on http://localhost:4200). But I highly doubt that's the issue.

Comment: I had a similar issue with fetch, it looks like you're doing some auth, so maybe it's related. `credentials: 'include'` solved it for me (See example in my repo [here](https://github.com/RUJodan/Source-React/blob/master/src/components/Login.jsx#L24)), along with JSON.stringify

Comment: @SterlingArcher Thanks! But now I'm getting this error:

`Failed to load http://localhost:3000/authenticate: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.`

Can you tell why? I really don't understand this stuff.

Comment: sorry I was sleeping! Did you make sure to send the headers along with the fetch request?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you are actually sending JSON. This looks like you are sending the raw string `anything`, which isn't JSON.

Comment: As I mentioned, I tried sending strings, JSON objects, stringified JSON objects, but no matter what, it always comes out to {}.

Comment: Well, whether or not you tried different things, your sample code is at the very least wrong for that reason. You should fix your sample code to be as correct as possible.